# bitbucket web: highlighted or greyed-out merge commits?

Tags: bitbucket

I'd like to know why, in the commits view of the bitbucket webui, I see some merge commits with the M greyed-out whereas others have it in color.

How can this be setup or how are they detected?

I wasn't able to find any documentation about this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is based on the commit comment. It must contain following lines:

```
Conflicts:
    src/app.cpp
```

If bitbucket detects this pattern in the commit comment, the merge commit will be highlighted in commits view. Otherwise, it will appear as greyed-out.

Comment: Similar issues, In PR, I can see two some auto commit with gray out, but There is nothing in diff tag in PR ! Means Both branch is same  ? No PR require ?

Comment: I'm looking at a merge commit that does not have that pattern in the comment and the highlighting is there. Maybe BB is highlighting the all the new commits from the merge(?). Edit: nvm, I see now that the highlighted commits are not merged but native to the branch