# Bitbucket commits page - greyed out/faded out commits?

Tags: bitbucket, commit

In `bitbucket` when I go to the 'commits' page to see my list of commits for a branch, I see that some commits are full brightness, but others are faded/greyed out. What is the meaning behind this?

I've seen one other answer regarding this on the entire internet (no mention in official Atlassan documentation), but the answer was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

These commits are likely merge commits, where BitBucket looks for a specific format in the commit comment:

> This behavior is based on the commit comment. It must contain following lines:
>
> ```
> Conflicts:
>     src/app.cpp
> ```
>
> If bitbucket detects this pattern in the commit comment, the merge commit will be highlighted in commits view. Otherwise, it will appear as greyed-out.

Source: [bitbucket web: highlighted or greyed-out merge commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922773/bitbucket-web-highlighted-or-greyed-out-merge-commits)